# android dashboard layout 3 and 2 columns

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to achieve this layout. I was trying to do a DashboardLayout. But any gridview I can have same number of columns. Do I need to use two gridviews? how about the lines? How can I draw those?

helpor any guideline much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why not a simple `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to use relative layout and place your dashboard component like explain here 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html
THE REF HERE :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

Comment: yes thanks, late night work has taken some troll one me. Did it with Relative layout :)